# Help me debug my SQL INSERT, please?

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling back some data from the twitter query API, and parsing it through PHP like so:

```
    $i =0;
    foreach ($tweetArray->results as $tweet) {
        $timeStamp = strtotime($tweet->created_at);
        $tweetDateTime = date('m-d-Y H:m:s', $timeStamp);
        if($i > 0){
            $SQL .= ',';
        }
        $SQL .= "(". $tweet->id .",'" . $tweet->from_user ."','". addslashes($tweet->profile_image_url) . "','". addslashes($tweet->text). "','" . $tweetDateTime ."')";
        $i++;
    }
    $SQL .= " ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 1=1";
```

This leaves me with a SQL statement looking like this:

```
INSERT 
    INTO 
        tblTwitterSubmit (tweetId, twitterAuthor, authorAvatar, tweetText, tweetDateTime)
    VALUES
    (111,'name','http://url.com','a string of text','03-04-2011 13:03:09'),
    (222,'anothername','http://url.com','another tweet','03-04-2011 12:03:51')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 1=1;
```

I am unfortunately getting the following error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1=1' at line 1`.

**Edit:**
The 1=1 is supposed to not do anything. The tweets don't change, and so if I pull the same one back twice for any reason, nothing will happen, but it also won't throw a duplicate key error.

**Re-edit:**
The problem appears to have something to do with the key field I was using, which was the id of tweet as assigned by twitter.

I re-factored the code anyway, since it seemed pretty evident that what I had read in articles as a "really-good-idea" wasn't. I now included a PDO submit inside the for loop so I just make a bunch of submissions instead of one long sql string.

Hopefully this is better practice.

Leaving this open for a couple minutes hoping for some feedback if this is the way to do it or not.

Comment: What is 1=1 meant to do, exactly? I'm no MySQL expert, but that looks mighty unnecessary (and, perhaps, invalid syntax) to me...

Comment: @rlb.usa: A quick glance at the `SQL` statement the OP posted shows that is not the case.

Comment: It's only there so that the database has something to do if there's a duplicate key, that way I don't get error messages.

Comment: If you're just looking to suppress warnings for duplicate keys, `1=1` is still going to be a syntax error.  Best practice is to handle the warning issued by mysql.  There's a way to suppress warnings on a per-function call basis in PHP, but I hesitate to bring them up -- it's considered very bad practice.

Comment: Interesting. I've seen plenty of "this evaluates to true" or "unduplicate key update 0+0" recomended in various articles online. What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're using the right syntax for [`on duplicate key update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) ?

Judging from it's manual's page, it seems you have to specify a column name, and not `1=1`.

From what I understand, if you want to indicate *"use the value from the values() clause when there's a duplicate"*, you should use something like this :

```
on duplicate key update your_col=values(your_col)
```

Quoting the relevant part :

> You can use the `VALUES(col_name)`
>   function in the `UPDATE` clause to
>   refer to column values from the
>   `INSERT` portion of the `INSERT ... ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statement.
>   
> In other words,
>   **`VALUES(col_name)` in the `ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause refers to
>   the value of `col_name` that would be
>   inserted**, had no duplicate-key
>   conflict occurred. 
> This
>   function is especially useful in
>   multiple-row inserts.

Then, as a sidenote, you must escape your strings using **the function that matches your API** -- probably [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](http://fr.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) -- and not the generic addslashes, which doesn't know about the specificities of your database engine.

Comment: Thank you for that second part, though the addslashes is only there as a placeholder. I originally wrote the statement using PDO, so I cannot use mysql_real_escape. It will be fixed before I finalize the code.

Comment: OK :-) Using prepared statements is even better !

Answer (score 4):

The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` requires a column name, something like this, assuming tweetId is the key column that's getting duplicates.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tweetId=tweetId+1
```

Your `1=1` doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to have something to do with the key field I was using, which was the id of tweet as assigned by twitter.

I re-factored the code anyway, since it seemed pretty evident that what I had read in articles as a "really-good-idea" wasn't. I now included a PDO submit inside the for loop so I just